# Off canvas menu is not hidden when resizing the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Please help!!!
Im working on the off canvas menu(https://codepen.io/oleksiukmary/pen/MEGpZj). The problem is when mobile menu is open and user resize the window - content has still transform property and overlay. How can i go back to initial parameters when user resizes the window? Should i just check via js if window resize is morethan 768px (my breakpoint) and then hide overlay and transform content?

My js:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav-toggle').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $('.content-wrap').css('transform', 'translateX(80%)');
    } else {
      $('.content-wrap').css('transform', 'translateX(0)');
    }
    $('body').toggleClass('overflow-hidden');
    $('#c-mask').toggleClass('is-active');
  });

  $('#c-mask').click(function() {
    $('#overlay').fadeOut('slow');
    $(this).removeClass('is-active');
    $('#nav-toggle').prop('checked', false);
    $('.content-wrap').css('transform', 'translateX(0)');
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes you're right. You need to add a resize handler and inside that, you need to check the new width of viewport/window and hide the menu, overlay, transform etc if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$( window ).resize(function()` to detect the window size and deactivate the offcanvas

```
  $( window ).resize(function() {
if ($(window).width() > 768) {
$('#overlay').fadeOut('slow');
$('#nav-toggle').prop('checked', false);
$('.content-wrap').css('transform', 'translateX(0)');
}
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if ($(window).width() > 768)`

Comment: no, it means if you opened the menu and resized it to more then 768, the offcanvas will deactivate

Comment: This condition says - hide overlay and remove transform when window width is less than 768, right? But desired behaviour is that on small screen sizes that sidebar menu appears and then if width becomes greater than 768, then things should go back to normal i.e overlay hidden and transform removed.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj , oh, yeah, got your point , sorry, update the code

Comment: It should be > 768px. Otherwise when menu is opened and width < 768px, whenever the user resizes a window menu is closed automatically. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code block

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  if($( window ).width() > 768) {
    $('.content-wrap').css('transform', 'translateX(0)');
  }
});
```